# Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setContent: not a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

my `markers` object is as following

```
'[["12.900922","80.227874","Name1","this is the first one"],["12.887818","80.227155","Name2","this is the II one"],["12.897482","80.22561","Name3","this is the III one"],["12.879158","80.23826","Name4","this is the IV one"],["12.898402","80.214313","Name5","this is the V one"],["12.915971","80.211824","Name6","this is the VI one"],["12.894637","80.235685","Name7","this is the VII one"],["12.894888","80.230631","Name8","this is the VIII one"]]'
```

I would like to popup some description using `google map` `setContent(infoWindowContent)` option

my `infoWindowContent` is

```
var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>' +markers[i][2]+ '</h3>' +
    '<p>' +markers[i][3]+ '</p></div>']
];
```

the error I'm facing now is 
`Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setContent: not a string`

here `markers[i][2]= 'Name2'` & `markers[i][3]= 'This is the first one'`

what is i'm doing wrong?

Comment: '<h3>'+markers[i][2]+'</h3>' like so

Comment: why is `infoWindowContent ` a multidemensional array that really only has one string in it?

Comment: the problem i'm facing is `Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setContent: not a string`

Answer (score 1):

```
var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>' + markers[i][2] + '</h3>' +
    '<p>' + markers[i][3] + '</p></div>']
];
```

Answer (score 1):

**if u are you using the return method**

infowindow.setContent(infowindow);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);

**remove the setContent line.**

use only

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

like google maps API documentation.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

like I use:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
var contentString = 'text here';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString
});

return function () {                   
infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
})(marker, i));
```